# Is there a way to schedule an iOS app to open at specific times?

Tags: ios, applications, automation

I was wondering if someone had any ideas on how (like the title says) I could schedule an app to open, say every hour. Workflow app unfortunately does not support the app I need opened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible due to iOS restrictions.

Comment: A little more depth would have been nice, but thanks!